# Arch system randomly lags after installing nvidia drivers via pacman

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia

Im using EndeavourOS on a Lenovo ideapad 3 15arh05, with kernel version on linux 5.13.13.arch1-1.

I just recently updated the system via pacman -Syy and -Syu, after which i installed the nvidia drivers via pacman -S nvidia.

Now the system is randomly freezing completely from time to time.

A bunch of kworker processes popped into top and almost always take 100% of the CPU,
while dmesg and journalctl messages that look like this :

```
               .
[ 2194.247877] eno1: mem_base_l = 0xffff, should be 0x4004 
               .
[ 2194.247880] eno1: mem_base_h = 0xffff, should be 0xc370 
               .
[ 2194.247884] eno1: resv_0x1c_l = 0xffff, should be 0x0000 
               .
[ 2194.247887] eno1: resv_0x1c_h = 0xffff, should be 0x0000 
               .
[ 2194.247891] eno1: resv_0x20_l = 0xffff, should be 0x0004 
               .
[ 2194.247895] eno1: resv_0x20_h = 0xffff, should be 0xc370 
               .
[ 2194.247898] eno1: resv_0x24_l = 0xffff, should be 0x0000 
               .
[ 2194.247901] eno1: resv_0x24_h = 0xffff, should be 0x0000 
               .
[ 2194.247905] eno1: ilr = 0xff, should be 0x04 
               .
[ 2194.247908] eno1: resv_0x2c_l = 0xffff, should be 0x17aa 
               .
[ 2194.247912] eno1: resv_0x2c_h = 0xffff, should be 0x38f7 
               .
[ 2194.248038] eno1: pci_sn_l = 0xffffffff, should be 0x684ce000 
               .
[ 2194.249247] eno1: pci_sn_h = 0xffffffff, should be 0x01000000 
               .
```

,which i guess is tied to the network manager, and

```
[ 2153.504278] [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
```

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That bug ("[drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!") has already been reported to the amdgpu developers: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/934

Comment: I have seen this post, but my problem does not match what is there. This is the only error message from amd, and the computer is still useable, albeit with hiccups.
The bulk of the problem comes from the first messages, the ones with eno1. I saw another post about this, and it apparently has something to do with the r8168 package.